# What does term per term multiplication of power series look like?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, rational-functions

Suppose we have two rational functions $f$ and $g$ on the complex plane, such that $f(0)=g(0)=1$. In a neighbourhood of $0$, we can write the following.
\begin{align}
f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} N_n^f t^n \\
g(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} N_n^g t^n
\end{align}
Now my question is, what does the following function look like?
\begin{align}
h(t) := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} N_n^f N_n^g t^n
\end{align}
Evidently, we have $h(0)=1$ and
\begin{align}
m! \left. \frac{d^m h}{dt^m} \right|_{t=0} = \left. \frac{d^m f}{dt^m} \right|_{t=0} \cdot \left. \frac{d^m g}{dt^m} \right|_{t=0}
\end{align}
However, I would like to have a formula that gives $h$ in terms of $f$ and $g$ explicitly, without having to refer to either the derivatives of $h$, or a series expansion.

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3526636, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/262821 – you'll probably find more with a search for “Hadamard product of rational functions.”

Comment: Yes. This was exactly what I needed. Thank you!